# How to stop elements moving other elements when positioned absolutely?

Tags: css, html

Using css, I'm trying to position my dropdown menu in mobile but there are some issues.

1. I've rotated it 270 degrees and this has left a space after it on the on right which increases page width.
2. I'd like to position it absolutely but doing so requires  negative margin-left, or margin right, which moves the line separating head and body to the right.

So do I position it absolutely, stop the white space appearing to the left and stop it moving other elements?

I've tried to reduce its width, which has no effect, and the further left I move it, the further left the grey line separating head and body goes.

Here is my working CSS.

```css
@media(max-width: 768px). {
  .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    right: 50% 
    margin-left: 110px;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="module-group right">    
                            <div class="module left">


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">  
 <ul id="menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-it
   em-3530" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3530 dropdown"><a title="Contact" href="https://4309.co.uk/contact/">Contact 
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-12515" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-12515"><a title="DRAWING DEVELOPMENT" href="https://4309.co.uk/drawing-development/">DRAWING DEVELOPMENT</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2997" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2997"><a title="SKETCHES" href="https://4309.co.uk/sketches-life-drawing/">SKETCHES</a></li>
```

[Here is a link to my personal site](https://4309.co.uk)

Basically I'm also trying to make it device compatible for all mobile handsets(responsive)

There are some side issues too, which are that one of the menu items rides up the page in certain devices.

When the menu is opened, there is a the big white space, when closed the space disappears.

The menu also moves according to which page you're on, not sure how that happens.

Comment: A common inquiry for questions askers is [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1366033), where the guidelines are *no*, not really.  Links degrade over time and it's better to include a [MCVE] in your question.

Comment: Thanks. Snack snippets doesn't work on mobile, I don't think but please find relevant html above

Comment: "I'd like to position it absolutely but doing so requires negative margin-left". Positioning it absolutely takes the element out of the flow, so applying a margin doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Applying `left` sorry....

Comment: @heretic Monkey basically i just want the width not to increase because if it does page width increases. When i apply position absolute, it's fine except page width increase, and it's not in the centre which means I have to put left or right px positioning.